# zf2 doctrine2 how to use tinyint datatype in entity column

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 ORM with ZF2.

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="tinyint", options={"default" = 1})
 */
protected $isActive;
```

How can I create tinyint type of column, as I can see in [support data type of doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html), it does not exist.

```
Commandline># ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Application\Entity\User' mapping is invalid:
* The field 'Application\Entity\User#isActive' uses a non-existant type 'tinyint'.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown column type "tinyint" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypeMap(). If this
  error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseT
  ypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.


orm:validate-schema
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [columnDefinition](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column), though it is not an ideal solution but serve the purpose.

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(columnDefinition="TINYINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL")
 */
protected $isActive;
```

columnDefinition: DDL SQL snippet that starts after the column name and specifies the complete (non-portable!) column definition. This attribute allows to make use of advanced RMDBS features. However you should make careful use of this feature and the consequences. SchemaTool will not detect changes on the column correctly anymore if you use “**columnDefinition**”.

Additionally you should remember that the “**type**” attribute still handles the conversion between PHP and Database values. If you use this attribute on a column that is used for joins between tables you should also take a look at [@JoinColumn](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn).

Comment: We had the same problem, but it resolved using `options={"default" : false}`

Answer (score 8):

There is no `tinyint` type in Doctrine 2. Reason is straightforward:

> A Doctrine type defines the conversion between PHP and SQL types,
>   independent from the database vendor you are using. All Mapping Types
>   that ship with Doctrine are fully portable between the supported
>   database systems.

You should pick one of these:

- `integer`: Type that maps a SQL INT to a PHP integer.
- `smallint`: Type that maps a database SMALLINT to a PHP integer.
- `bigint`: Type that maps a database BIGINT to a PHP string.

Official docs here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

Comment: So, and how is one supposed to work with an existing database that has tinyint???

Comment: I think edigu's point here is that if you stick to what Doctrine has available, later you should be able to switch to any of the supported database vendors that Doctrine supports. If you use tinyint with MySQL by later have to switch to PostgreSQL, for example, you'll run into problems. But yeah, this answer doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: I think ~99.9% of applications never changes database vendor, so dropping a feature just for that is nonsense imho

Answer (score 7):

Imo you should just use the column type bool Doctrine then will convert this into tinyint in mysql for you.

```
/**
 * @var bool
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 *
 * @Form\Exclude()
 */
protected $isActive;
```

You could also define a default value like so:

```
...
protected $isActive = true;
...
```

But rather then doing that you should set in in your populate.

Comment: boolean has only two values(true, false) I need more than two, Integer is not optimal solution. tinyint can be used for this purpose in mysql, smallint is closest option available in doctrine2 for tinyint. or use columndefination

Comment: but naming convention vise isActive should only have 2 states imo. Either active or inactive what is your 3rd possibility here? If you really want a tinyint type you could check out http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types . But it looks a bit overkill on just achieving the tinyint type. Your answer may be the easiest to implement and you should go with it if you really need a tiny int.

Comment: @cptnk there is another state, ``null``. Not usable on OP user case, but convenient.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches here, i faced all most similar problem, Doctrine allows you to create any data type that you think you need or that is not avaialable in its packages. 2nd Approach is to use Small Int which may not be optimal solution but i think it servers the puropose. I have seen some developers use Int type as well but still it may not be optimal solution.